# jQuery - Toggle .html text?

Tags: jquery

Why won't this work?

http://jsfiddle.net/PdwJ6/

HTML

```
<a href="#" id="showMore">Before</a>
```

JS

```
$('#showMore').click(function() {

$(this).toggle(
function () {
    $(this).html('<a href="#">After</a>');},
function () {
    $(this).html('<a href="#">Before</a>');
});
});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not sure what's up with JsFiddle.net, but I can't post a demo.

You're nesting two functions within each other (`.click()` and `.toggle()`), and `.toggle()` handles a `click`, so that might be causing conflict. Also, use `text()` instead of `html()`:

**HTML**:

```
<a href="#" id="showMore">Before</a>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
$('#showMore').toggle(function() {
    $(this).text('Before');
}, function() {
    $(this).text('After');
});
```

Comment: "This method signature was deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 1.9."
https://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/
What it now does is just animate the clicked object out of sight.

Answer (score 23):

Blender has the appropriate answer, but we can also generalize your question into a simple jQuery plugin:

```
$.fn.toggleText = function(t1, t2){
  if (this.text() == t1) this.text(t2);
  else                   this.text(t1);
  return this;
};
```

Your code would then look like:

```
$('#showMore').click(function(){
  $(this).toggleText('Before', 'After');
})
```

Comment: Found it useful and different from other answers.

Comment: Based on the intent of what OP is trying to do, this should be the accepted answer. (sorry to all for dragging up a 2-year-old post)

Answer (score 18):

A simple solution for toggling after a click:

```
$('#showMore').on('click', function(){
    $(this).html() == "after" ? $(this).html('before') : $(this).html('after');
});
```

Comment: should use === instead of ==

Comment: why make it longer `$(this).html(($(this).html() == "after") ? 'before' : 'after')`

Answer (score 8):

This is a reduced / "more compact" version of the same answer here: ["A simple solution for toggling after a click"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20075721/2817442).

```
$('#showMore').on('click', function(){
    $(this).html($(this).html() == 'after' ? 'before' : 'after');
});
```

Of course this needs jQuery plugin for it to work.

Comment: This code may work but it makes a poor answer as there is no description of what it does or how it answers the question or why the code in the question does not work.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code to make this a wholesome answer

Answer (score 3):

You are binding a `click` to the `<a/>` and than inside of that you are binding a `toggle()` to it.

If you simply want to toggle you can leave off the `click()`.

```
$('#showMore').toggle(
    function() {
       $(this).html('<a href="#">After</a>');
    }, 
    function() {
       $(this).html('<a href="#">Before</a>');
});
```

With that being said you are placing an `<a/>` inside of another `<a/>` Is that really what you want?  Or you you just want to replace the `.text()`? `.text("Before")`

[Jsfiddle example of `toggle()`](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/PdwJ6/6/)

Answer (score 1):

because you are nesting a `<a>` inside another, resulting in something like `<a href="#" id="#showMore"><a href="">After</a></a>`

You should just use `$(this).text('After')` and same with Before

I guess you wanted to use [`replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/) which is not very efficient in this situation because only the text changes.

++ the toggle bug spotted in the other answers. Kudos to them ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.fn.extend({
    toggleText: function (a, b){
        var that = this;
            if (that.text() != a && that.text() != b){
                that.text(a);
            }
            else
            if (that.text() == a){
                that.text(b);
            }
            else
            if (that.text() == b){
                that.text(a);
            }
        return this;
    }
});
```

Use as:

```
$("#YourElementId").toggleText('After', 'Before');
```