# How to run a href in background to update database php like button

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want this `<a href>` to run href in background onclick using ajax jquery. I tried to do it but i don't know jquery nicely.

```
<a href="https://www.username.com/liked/$profile->profile_id " class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm"><i class="far fa-thumbs-up me-1"></i>Like</a>
```

This is the code that needed it please tell me where the function should be placed and the jquery code to send this `href` in ajax jquery.
And it show be in loop of changing `href` path betweeen the click of button like example.com/like/1 on first click and example.com/unlike/1 on second click and the loop continue making the multiple press of button possible.

Comment: What did work, what did not work? "I want code" is no question. Where is `$profile->profile_id` coming from? You also need to return false to the `onclick` immediately, not from the callback.

Comment: `thisLike` will be a string, not a reference to a `form` element, so calling `serialize()` on that isn't going to work.

Comment: Same applies to `attr('href')`. You probably meant to put `onclick='eachlike(this)'`

Comment: $profile->profile is coming from controller and contain the id of the specific profile.

Comment: what can be used in place of serialize() then?

Comment: You don't need to replace `serialize`, you need to replace what `thislike` is (see comment above). `$profile->profile is coming from controller` so that is replaced inside the JS already?

Comment: 1)it is a laravel based application and i just need to change each(this.href) to each(this)?

Comment: No, you need to change `eachlike(this.href)` to `eachlike(this)`. But that does not seem to be the only problem. If this is inside a blade template, where are the curly brackets around the profile id?

Comment: ooo ok I improved the curly bracked and eachlike are there any other issues too?

Comment: Yes, see my very first comment.

Comment: i tried still there is not solution?

Comment: 1. Tell us what outcome you expect and what the real outcome is. 2. Add debug info to your question. "I tried" und "not solution" does not help us help you.

Comment: ok then this is passing through controller file only becuase due to infinite loading

Comment: can I have a prite chatroom with you volkerschulz

Comment: Nope. You simply need to provide the information I've asked for. If you don't want to or are unable to, we can't help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the sample code you've asked for. There are two link elements with different href attributes. When clicked, an ajax request will be fired to whatever is specified as the href and on success the respective span will be filled with a string and be shown for 3 seconds.

```
<a onclick='return eachlike(this)' href="https://www.jamarkoho.com/liked/1" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm">
    <i class="far fa-thumbs-up me-1"></i>
    Like <span class="here"></span>
</a>

<a onclick='return eachlike(this)' href="https://www.jamarkoho.com/liked/2" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm">
    <i class="far fa-thumbs-up me-1"></i>
    Like <span class="here"></span>
</a>

<script>
    function eachlike(thislike) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: $(thislike).attr('href'),
            success: function(response) {
                $(thislike).find('.here').html('Done!').show().delay(3000).fadeOut();
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

To actually toggle the href (like / unlike), use something like this:

```
<a onclick='return eachlike(this)' href="https://www.jamarkoho.com/liked/1" data-toggle-href="https://www.jamarkoho.com/unlike/1" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm">
    <i class="far fa-thumbs-up me-1"></i>
    Like <span class="here"></span>
</a>

<a onclick='return eachlike(this)' href="https://www.jamarkoho.com/liked/2" data-toggle-href="https://www.jamarkoho.com/unlike/2" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-sm">
    <i class="far fa-thumbs-up me-1"></i>
    Like <span class="here"></span>
</a>

<script>
    function eachlike(thislike) {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: $(thislike).attr('href'),
            success: function(response) {
                $(thislike).find('.here').html('Done!').show().delay(3000).fadeOut();
                toggleHref(thislike);
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
    function toggleHref(thislike) {
        let currentHref = $(thislike).attr('href');
        let newHref = $(thislike).data('toggle-href');
        $(thislike).attr('href', newHref);
        $(thislike).data('toggle-href', currentHref);
    }
</script>
```

The second function toggles between `href` and new attribute `data-toggle-href`.

Comment: this is working fine but how to make the link on href to get change into like and unlinke links in multiple click? Like first click href='ccc/liked/1' and second 'cc/unlike/1' and same loop continues?

Comment: Could you do me a favor and post a new question for this? There are multiple ways and it might be of help to others to outline them not in a comment but in an answer. It's hard to put code here. Put the link to the new question here in the comments.

Comment: i would surely do that but my profile isn't supported for another another by stackoverflow.

Comment: You should probably edit and improve your question then! https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans

Comment: But I'm going to see if I can extend my answer above later today.

Comment: ooo ok i will inform you when i post a new question

Comment: yeah i just updated my question please post a new answer volkerschulz

Comment: it is not working the browser is showing Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://www.example.com/unlike/220. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null). and this too "(Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200"

Comment: Yeah, because you're not allowed to request something from `example.com` when on a different domain. You need to add your **actual** links.

Comment: I am doing it on the actually domain only in my live website I am just hiding it here.

Comment: It is a laravel project what can be done?Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 200

Comment: You're getting the error `Cross-Origin Request Blocked` only if you're trying to access one domain from a different domain. It's a security feature of your browser.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Comment: It is showing cors error in example.com xhr to example.com/liked/1 where do i need to add Access-Control-Allow-Origin : * in my laravel project

Comment: There's no way it shows that error when requesting `example.com/xxx/yyy` from `example.com`. Follow the link I've posted.

Comment: after changing href='example.com/like/1' to href='/like/1' it is working!

Comment: You weren't using the same domain before then. ;)

Comment: This is not a problem with the code, it is a new question again!

Comment: Find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5584010/jquery-toggle-html-text (the one with the most upvotes). Please do your research and try to learn. This is what SO is all about.

Comment: can you explain how the javascript functions are interacting with the html component

Comment: what does `eachlike(this)` onclick `this` contain?

Comment: The HTML DOM element the onclick attribute belongs to.

Comment: `this` means that specific DOM element. I am correct?

Comment: Correct, the element that has that particular onclick attribute. The `a` in this case.